# Why are my data not displayed in this Pandas graph?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` `daily_data_f_no_nr` with following content (result of `print(daily_data_f_no_nr)`):

```
          Day  Total TODO/TODOE count  First Derivative
0  2020-05-16                      35               0.0
1  2020-05-17                      35               0.0
2  2020-05-18                      35               0.0
3  2020-05-19                      35               0.0
4  2020-05-20                      35               0.0
..        ...                     ...               ...
74 2020-07-29                     152               0.0
75 2020-07-30                     152               0.0
76 2020-07-31                     152               0.0
77 2020-08-01                     152               0.0
78 2020-08-02                     152               0.0
```

I want to create a line chart where

- `Day` is on the x axis and
- `Total TODO/TODOE count` and `First Derivative` is on the y axis.

I use the following code for this:

```
fig = daily_data_f_no_nr.plot(kind='line', figsize=(20, 16), fontsize=26, xticks=daily_data_f_no_nr['Day'], yticks=daily_data_f_no_nr['Total TODO/TODOE count'], y=['Total TODO/TODOE count', 'First Derivative']).get_figure()
fig.savefig(CHART_FILE)
```

`CHART_FILE` looks like this:

[image: Incorrect image (actual result)]

No lines representing `Total TODO/TODOE count` and `First Derivative` are drawn.

What am I doing wrong? How do I need to change the code above in order to generate a graph like shown below (day on the x axis,
`Total TODO/TODOE count` and `First Derivative` on the y)?

[image: Expected/desired diagram]

**Update 1:** If I change the code to

```
fig = daily_data_f_no_nr.plot(kind='line', figsize=(20, 16), fontsize=26, xticks=daily_data_f_no_nr['Day'], yticks=daily_data_f_no_nr['Total TODO/TODOE count'],x='Day', y=['Total TODO/TODOE count', 'First Derivative']).get_figure()
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py\todo-count-delta.py", line 113, in <module>
    fig = daily_data_f_no_nr.plot(kind='line', figsize=(20, 16), fontsize=26, xticks=daily_data_f_no_nr['Day'], yticks=daily_data_f_no_nr['Total TODO/TODOE count'],x='Day', y=['Total TODO/TODOE count', 'First Derivative']).get_figure()
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 847, in __call__
    return plot_backend.plot(data, kind=kind, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\__init__.py", line 61, in plot
    plot_obj.generate()
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py", line 266, in generate
    self._adorn_subplots()
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py", line 476, in _adorn_subplots
    ax.set_xticks(self.xticks)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 3350, in set_xticks
    ret = self.xaxis.set_ticks(ticks, minor=minor)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1755, in set_ticks
    self.set_view_interval(min(ticks), max(ticks))
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1892, in setter
    setter(self, min(vmin, vmax, oldmin), max(vmin, vmax, oldmax),
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.float64' and 'Timestamp'
```

**Update 2:** Here is the output of `print(daily_data_f_no_nr.info())`:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 79 entries, 0 to 78
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column                  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------                  --------------  -----
 0   Day                     79 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 1   Total TODO/TODOE count  79 non-null     int64
 2   First Derivative        79 non-null     float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), int64(1)
memory usage: 2.0 KB
None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1: use `Day` column as `x` parameter

You should add the `x = 'Day'` parameter:

```
fig = daily_data_f_no_nr.plot(kind='line', figsize=(20, 16), fontsize=26, xticks=daily_data_f_no_nr['Day'], yticks=daily_data_f_no_nr['Total TODO/TODOE count'], x = 'Day', y=['Total TODO/TODOE count', 'First Derivative']).get_figure()
```

With the data you provided above (only beginning and end of the dataframe):

[image]

---

## Option 2: set `Day` column as the index of the dataframe

You can set the `Day` column as the index of the dataframe with:

```
daily_data_f_no_nr.set_index('Day', inplace = True)
```

Now you can plot it with:

```
fig = daily_data_f_no_nr.plot(kind='line', figsize=(20, 16), fontsize=26, xticks=daily_data_f_no_nr.index, yticks=daily_data_f_no_nr['Total TODO/TODOE count'], y=['Total TODO/TODOE count', 'First Derivative']).get_figure()
```

And you will get the same plot as above.

---

## Complete Code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

daily_data_f_no_nr = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
daily_data_f_no_nr['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(daily_data_f_no_nr['Day'], format = '%Y-%m-%d')

daily_data_f_no_nr.set_index('Day', inplace = True)

fig = daily_data_f_no_nr.plot(kind='line', figsize=(20, 16), fontsize=26, xticks=daily_data_f_no_nr.index, yticks=daily_data_f_no_nr['Total TODO/TODOE count'], y=['Total TODO/TODOE count', 'First Derivative']).get_figure()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your recommendation. See *Update 1* in the text of the question.

Comment: That error could be due to missing values, please check for them. Moreover, there could be "strange" values in one column (maybe a `NaN`?); please, provide output of `print(daily_data_f_no_nr.info())`

Comment: Ad *please, provide output of `print(daily_data_f_no_nr.info())`*:  See update 2.

Comment: Could you provide your dataframe, in order to do a check?

Comment: Before generating the chart, I do `daily_data_f_no_nr['First Derivative'].fillna(0, inplace=True)` which should remove any `NaN` values.

Comment: Also, the CSV file that is generated by `daily_data_f_no_nr.to_csv(CSV_FILE, sep=';')` (before the code that creates the chart) does not contain any `NaN` values. There is the header in the file (`;Day;Total TODO/TODOE count;First Derivative`) and rows like `9;2020-05-25;35;0.0` and `66;2020-07-21;151;116.0`.

Comment: I updated my answer. If you get an error again, please, edit the question and post your entire dataset in order to perform a check.